# Spring-Data-Cassandra SchemaAction not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to configure Cassandra in my application by extending `CassandraAutoConfiguration`

I'm using spring `CassandraRepository` for DB access and classes with `o.s.d.cassandra.core.mapping.Table` annotation for defining my tables.

I've also configured following property, along with other required properties for cluster

```
spring: 
  data:
   cassandra:
     schema-action: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
```

But No table get created in Cassandra upon application startup.
`schemaAction` in `CassandraProperties`  is not working.

If I programmatically create tables upon startup in my `ApplicationRunner` by using `cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute(...)` then everything works fine.

In this case I am able to use my repository. find() and save() methods.
Just to prove that my @table classes are correctly written

Answer (score 4):

Here is the behaviour I noticed. This is not only true for this particular key in `application.yaml`

- When you don't create any bean extending `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` spring-data will read every key matching `spring.data.*` in `application.yaml` including the schema-action you provided. (by CONVENTION). I don't seen any issue with the file you provided, as a matter of fact  I have a working sample [here](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-data-starter)
- When you create a bean extending `AbstractCassandraConfiguration`, now this is your job to implements explicitly the values you want as such please add in your class. Also you will need ro provide explicitly annotation `@EnableCassandraRepositories`

```
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.schema-action}")
private String schemaAction;
    
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
  return SchemaAction.valueOf(schemaAction);
}
```

On top of this I would like to advise NOT USING IT AT ALL. Spring Data works like a charm but here are my concerns:

- Creating a table is not only a matter of matching the data model. Indeed what about Compaction Strategy based on your use case or TTL or any metadata.
- We assume you know how to build a primary key properly with Partitions key and Clustering column but what if you need to store the exact same object in 2 tables because you have 2 different queries on it. (remember: I you need ALLOW FILTERING anywhere in your application=> your data model is probably wrong.

Comment: 1- I've spring.data.(contact-points/username/password/keyspace-name)in yml. 
   schema-action is not working.....

Comment: 2- `DID-NOT` not create bean by extending `AbstractCassandraConfiguration`..
   created `@Configuration` class by extending `o.s.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration` to create cluster `@Bean`....

Comment: 3- Yes, I've created one main `@Table` & 3 lookup `@Table`..four `o.s.data.cassandra.repo.CassandraRepository`..
   Main table class has `@PrimaryKey` as a UUID (`PartitionKey`) & 3 lookup classes have Primarykey as Java class `o.s.d.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClass`.. 
   All 3 java classes have one field as `PartitionKey` and remaing as `Clusteringkey`

Comment: `CassandraAutoConfiguration` does  not contain any reference to SCHEMA, you should extend `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` to customize. Check 7.3.1 here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config. Also you speak about `Cluster` bean but this one does not exist anymore replaced by `CqlSession`

Comment: Thanks @clunven you are right `CassandraProperties` is used inside `CassandraAutoConfiguration` but class is not using `SchemaAction` field in code. thus its ignored.......But As You mentioned under your concerns, I realize, I should not create schema upon appliciton startup by `@table` definition, coz Metadata will be different in various environments, 'eg'  `replication_factor` & other fields.  So `I'll not use SchemaAction=CreateIfNotExists` its good for POC but not for running apps in production...thanks for your suggestions. for POC in future, I'll extend AbstractCassandraConfiguration